# Join table with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have mysql table like this :

[image]

and the result is :

[image]

coloumn total = nilai1+nilai2
coloumn saran = 
- iF total >= ((max(total)-min(total))+min(total) then mayor, minor from table 1.
- else butuh from table 2.
But, max (total) and min(total) just count for the same Bidang.

How to show coloumn saran in result?

Comment: Pick some SQL book and learn Join.

Comment: Here is good [MySQL:Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+join?sort=votes&pageSize=50) Q&As

Comment: Huh, I read, and reread, I understand nothing! Where are nilai1 and 2 coming from? What exactly do you want!

Comment: Nilai1 and nilai2 ignored coming from because nilai1 and nilai1 is input from java aplication, i ask how to compute saran coloumn with that condition formating.

Comment: at least show us some SQL that you actually tried to use.

Comment: I found [this site](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page) useful when learning SQL